# AWS Cognito: unknown error when logging in the admin created user for the first time

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

Whenever I try logging in a user with status **FORCE_PASSWORD_CHANGE** for the first time, I am getting this error in the **OnFailure** callback function.

```
code:"UnknownError"
message:"200"
name:"UnknownError"
statusCode:200
```

When I click login button, the following function executes.

```
logInUser({username, password}){
    const p = new Promise((res, rej)=> {
        var authenticationData = {
            Username: username,
            Password: password,
        };
        var authenticationDetails = new AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);

        var userData = {
            Username: username,
            Pool: UserPool
        };
        var cognitoUser = new CognitoUser(userData);
        cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
            onSuccess: function (result) {
                alert("Success")
                console.log('access token + ' + result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken());
                console.log('idToken + ' + result.idToken.jwtToken);
                res({result})
            },

            onFailure: function (err) {
                console.log("Got an error")
                console.log(err);
                rej(err)
            },
        });
    });
    return p;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass in a callback for newPasswordRequired to authenticateUser.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-identity-user-pools-javascript-example-authenticating-admin-created-user.html

```
cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
    onSuccess: function (result) {
        res({result})
    },
    onFailure: function (err) {
        rej(err)
    },
    newPasswordRequired: function(userAttributes, requiredAttributes) {
        console.log("User needs new password");
        res({userAttributes, requiredAttributes});
    },
});
```

Comment: But when I use the edited version, it showed 'result' is not defined.

Comment: Also how can I get new password from the user? I tried to navigate to resetpassword component, get new password from user, stored as state and called cognitoUser.completeNewPasswordChallenge(this.state.repassword, null, this) in the new component. there are no errors but user pool status is not changed.

Comment: Updated it shouldn't have had res({result}).  
I think (I could be wrong) you need to call the completeNewPasswordChallenge when the callback newPasswordRequired is being called as part of authenticateUser.  My approach has been to just store the temp credentials and recall authenticateUser a second time once the user has entered a new password and call completeNewPasswordChallenge then.